# Specified file 'sql.txt' does not contain a usable HTTP request (with parameters)

Tags: mysql, security, httprequest, sql-injection, sqlmap

Whenever I am Using - **sqlmap -r sql.txt --dbms=MYSQL --dbs --batch** following result get displayed.

```
└─# sqlmap -r sql.txt --dbms=MYSQL --dbs --batch
```

[!] legal disclaimer: Usage of sqlmap for attacking targets without prior mutual consent is illegal. It is the end user's responsibility to obey all applicable local, state and federal laws. Developers assume no liability and are not responsible for any misuse or damage caused by this program

[*] starting @ 09:45:06 /2021-09-25/

[INFO] parsing HTTP request from 'sql.txt'

**[CRITICAL] specified file 'sql.txt' does not contain a usable HTTP request (with parameters)**

[*] ending @ 09:45:06 /2021-09-25/

**BUT when I see the content of sql.txt file with cat command show nothing.**

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Desktop/sqlmap]
└─# ls -la
total 72
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Sep 25 08:51 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Sep  5 18:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 20 14:18 docs
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 47756 Jun 11 09:09 map.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   335 Jun  3 17:27 new.txt
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Sep 25 08:49 sqlmap
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   554 Sep 25 08:34 sql.txt
                                                                                                                                                                         
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Desktop/sqlmap]
└─# cat sql.txt 
                                                                                                                                                                         
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Desktop/sqlmap]
└─#
```

**And then if I tried to see content of sql.txt with nano command then It show all file data.**

```
┌──(rootkali)-[~/Desktop/sqlmap]
└─# nano sql.txt   
                                                                               
POST /doLogin HTTP/1.1

Host: demo.testfire.net

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Content-Length: 35

Origin: http://demo.testfire.net

Connection: close

Referer: http://demo.testfire.net/login.jsp

Cookie: JSESSIONID=D5B396CF6FE3B67C4DF520346B5C889E

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1


uid=test&passw=test&btnSubmit=Login
```

I am not able to use SQLMap with -r please help me

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags - if indeed the RDBMS is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging into the source code of sqlmap on github, i found that there is a "bias" towards the input file being a raw dump of a http request intercepted by burpsuite or webscarab. Any other file (manually copy-pasted for instance from a web browser's http traffic as seen in the debug console) is somehow not ok.

So, the workaround i would suggest is to fire up burp suite (i have not yet worked with webscarab, so cannot comment on it), capture the http traffic of the request you are intending to analyse, copy paste the raw http traffic from burpsuite, into a text file and provide that file as the input to sqlmap with the -r switch.

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on the request windows section in intruder or repeater whichever you're currently in then click 'Save File' then save as a text file wherever you want. Then use the file as input using the '-r' flag as you did.
I believe the issue comes with encoding as manually copy pasting affects the end of line, carriage return characters. This possibly makes them incompatible for sqlmap.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue when I tried to exploit SQL injection in a GET request via sqlmap. however, you can use the asterisk * in a specific location within a GET request, even if it doesn't contain any parameters. By placing the asterisk * at a designated spot in the URL where you suspect a SQL injection vulnerability, SQLMap can effectively test for SQL injection at that particular location. This approach has resolved this issue for me.